# How to turn off Ripple Animation on Tabs [Android]?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

How do I turn Off Ripple Animation only for the Tabs ? I have tried to change this in the Config File

```
 activator : "highlight"
```

But that sets no highlight to all buttons.

I want to turn off Ripple Animation  just for Tabs ?

EDIT 1:

I wanted to remove the effect for the `ion-tabs`

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="paper"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="settings"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as shown below inside the `app.module.ts` file.

**Globally**

***app.module.ts***

```
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
    platforms: { 
      android: { 
        activator: 'none' 
     } 
  } 
}
```

**Only for ion-tab:**

You have to deal with CSS hack here on page component.No framework-level support for this.

***.html***

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="people" class="disable-ripple"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="paper" class="disable-ripple"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="settings" class="disable-ripple"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

***.scss***

```
.ios,
.md,
.wp {
    .disable-ripple ion-tab-effect {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that switch off Ripple Effect for all buttons and everywhere else in the App?

Comment: Yes, it is a **global effect**.what do you need to see then?

Comment: can you show the `html` code where you need to remove this effect?

Comment: Added the HTML code to my question. I wanted to remove the effect only for `ion-tabs`

Answer (score 3):

In Ionic 4, buttons have a CSS custom properties so you can do:

```
.disable-ripple {
    --ripple-color: transparent;

  &:hover {
      background: unset !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: this method works on ion-segment too!

Answer (score 2):

I found a Hacky Solution

```
ion-tabs .button-effect {
 display:none !important;
}
```

Looks like the button-effect is what "draws" the Ripple. So I just disabled the effect for all descendants of `ion-tabs`

I wrote that css in my *variables.scss*

EDIT 1: 
Nope. This too sets the `.button-effect` class to `display:none` globally. My Question was to set it only for a single `ion-tab` element.

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 4 just use the iOS mode:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
     <ion-tab-button tab="tab1" mode="ios">
```